# Magento 2 CMS page Editor not showing

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.3, magento2.3.0, tinymce

I am working on **magento 2.3.0**

When I try to edit a **cms page** on the **admin**, the **content section** is **blank**, with console **error** that **tinymce** is missing or **404**. please see attached screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: any solution for the issue?

Comment: are you got solution?

Answer (score 0):

As you see, your JS files are failed to load, for this case, you can follow the below steps.

Run Static Deploy.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Then clear cache.

```
php bin/magento cache/clear
```

Then give permission to your cache and pub files.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```

After all, this, try to load the CMS page section again. Hope this will do in the most case.

If it's still not fixed, check you might has missed the JS folder.

Comment: checked still nothing works.